# Navigation arc memory not released

Tags: ios, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I have two table table controllers A and B.
A has a list of items and when an item is clicked, it pushes to B.
The problem is that when B was shown, the instrutment indicated a live memory increase, but it did not decreased when I clicked on back button. 
The dealloc method in B was executed but the memory seemed changed slightly. 
I checked that B was not retained anywhere else so what may the reasons that can cause this problem?

In B, there are many textfields, labels which are nonatomic and strong. I draw them in codes rather than using xibs. If I commented the codes for initializing them and adding them to the table header view, then the problem is gone.

I use Arc and simulator 6.1 by the way.

Comment: If you're doing a lot of drawing are you making sure to call CFRelease/CGRelease etc.? What happens when you run the static analyzer on your code?

Comment: Is the `leaks` tool reporting anything? Also, what are you doing on B? Any images (being cached with `imageNamed`) any network activity? How much memory are you talking about? Depending upon what you do in B, it's not at all unusual that you won't see live bytes go a bit down as iOS does all sorts of things behind the scenes that could affect it. I'd only worry about (a) reported leaks; and (b) significant lost of "live bytes" that are not relieved on `didReceiveMemoryWarning`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that some of the textfields/labels inside B might have some strong reference to B itself making it impossible for arc to release them cause B has a strong pointer to and element inside it and this element has a strong pointer to B.

As far as I know thats not the default behaviour of textfields/labels, but maybe you've subclassed them...

Hard to try anything other than guessing with that little amount of information you gave

Comment: As far as I know thats not the default behaviour of textfields/labels
Can I ask what is the defualt behaviour of them, if I do not want to use xib?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the views to be accessible in the view controller context?  Can you not assign a tag to them and retrieve them from the tableview header when you need to change them?